# Can I add peanut butter to cook and serve pudding to make peanut butter pie? If so, do I use less liquid?

Tags: dessert

I'm wanting to make a peanut butter pie using vanilla cook and serve pudding. Can I do this and would I need to use less liquid?

Answer (score 4):

Welcome! Per [allrecipes](https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/22914/ez-peanut-butter-pie-ii/) , yes you can, and no change liquid is needed. The recipe in the link calls for a pre-made graham cracker crust and uses 1 cup of peanut butter.

The instructions read as:

> Prepare cook and serve pudding as directed on package. Stir in peanut butter. Bring mixture to a boil and pour into graham cracker crust. Allow to cool.

If you do a Google search, there are also many recipes available that use instant pudding.